# Stop logo and background color scrolling down using css

Tags: html, css, magento

This is demo site, so I am giving credentials. Without giving credentials it is not possible to get an answer.

Please visit this link: http://2.kidsdial.com/customer/account/login

Login with email: kidsdial2@gmail.com password : kidsdial2

Then click here: http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

Keep on scrolling. You can see

"Logo and its background color" is keep on coming at the middle.

I want to avoid this. I want to keep the logo and in its original position when scrolling down.

I want to keep the logo and its background color at constant position, it should not be visible when we are scrolling.

I am using this css:

```
<style>

.wk_mp_btn1 {background: #3fbdf7 none repeat scroll 0 0;color: #fff;}
.social-icons {
      display:none !important; // for removing social icons
    }


</style>

<style>

.div_link-cart { display:none !important; /* remove cart button */  }
.header_search { display:none !important; }
.inner_menu    { display:none !important  }  




.welcome-msg   { display:none !important  }


.grid_6.pull_18.col-left.sidebar > div:last-child {
    display: none;  /* remove complete my acccount section */ 
}    
.breadcrumbs  {  display:none !important  /* remove home > My account */ } 

.block-title  {  display:none !important  /* remove markeplace text */ } 

ul.wk_cont_ul li {
    display: inline-block;

}


.wk_cont_ul  { 
 // add menu background color
}


.wk_cont_ul_one 


{

    position:relative;
    left:640px;
    bottom:69px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:13px;
    list-style-type: none;
}


    ul.wk_cont_ul_one li

    { display: inline-block;}


</style>


<style type="text/css" media="screen"> #horizontalmenu ul { padding:1; margin:1; list-style:none; } #horizontalmenu li { float:left; position:relative; padding-right:100; display:block; border:0px solid #CC55FF; border-style:inset; } #horizontalmenu li ul { display:none; position:absolute; } #horizontalmenu li:hover ul{ display:block; background:white; height:auto; width:8em; } #horizontalmenu li ul li{ clear:both; border-style:none;} 



</style>


<style>

.mymenu  {

    font-size:17px;
    color : white;   // increasse menu font size and color
}

.wk_cont_ul 
 {
    position:relative;
    bottom:50px;
    background:yellow;

}

.widget.widget-static-block  {  display:none !important   } 




.mymenu li { margin-right:10px; }
.mymenu li a{ text-decoration: none;padding: 5px; }
  .mymenu li a:link{ text-decoration: none; }
.mymenu li a:hover{ text-decoration: none;background:#ffff00; }



</style>

<!-- for increasing products list table size -->

<style>
.fieldset {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 49%;
}




.fieldset {
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.hor-scroll{
    width: 100% !important;
}

</style>



<!-- for menu and logo color -->

<style>

#horizontalmenu .mymenu > li {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    width: 100px;
}
#main_header .header-container .header {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
#horizontalmenu{
    margin-top: -5px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I don't undestand the issue. You want that the header is fixed at the top of the page when scrolling down and keep it's position when you are at the top of the page, right?

Comment: i want to keep logo and its background color  at constant position, it should not visible when we are scrolling.....

Comment: can you edit the html of that page? There is a function at the end of the page that fixes the header

Comment: this is complete code of that page : http://pastebin.com/gFepQmAy please check this.....

Comment: I don't see that line of code. You can overwrite the rule just by using css. In your css file you can add `position: relative !important;` to your `#main_header`
This will overwrite the position fixed of your header

Comment: Is header position fixed if so remove it

Comment: @lecya , please post your comment as answer.....

Comment: @CY5 using lecya solution, its fine now....

Comment: The fixed position is given by a js function dynamically added at the end of the html code. He can't remove the fixed position unless he knows how that script is added

Comment: @lecya i am new to programming, i will try it also....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the rule just by using css.
In your css file you can add `position: relative !important;` to your `#main_header` This will overwrite the position fixed of your header

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then you can use this navbar-fixed-top in your class

```css
# menu-id
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div><nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"></div>
```